# Windows Metro: how to create a horizontal div without listview?

Tags: listview, layout, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to create a basic horizontal layout, with some pictures, text and links. Some pictures are bigger (100% vertical), some are smaller (50%) and there is some text in between.

I studied the ListView but it does not seem to fit what i want (without huge complexity) because all my pictures (itens) have a different layout and there is also some adhoc text.

It would be great if I could use the layout of the ListView without all of its complications, data sources and stuff. I don't have actual data, just a horizontal layout with specific images, text and links.

Can anyone give me a direction about this? I'm using Metro with Javascript + HTML.

In plain HTML, I'd probably use a div with a fixed-width of, say, 4000px.

Metro programming presents many new concepts, and the docs and not very clear yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your items are all the same size (or can make them thus), you should be able to use a "flexbox":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

I Adore flexbox.

Comment: Thanks @dhopton, we solved the question using -ms-flexbox in the container and inline-block in the children.

Comment: You shouldn't need inline block on the children